# How to make mymodule_preprocess_node run only once?

Tags: 8, hooks

We have a custom `mymodule` that calls `mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables)` hook. When we add `ksm($variables);` to the hook, we are finding the message is printed multiple times (average has been 5x).

How to make `mymodule_preprocess_node` run only one time?

I am needing to run this hook because I want to check to see if a field is populated with some value then perform some other logic.

Example:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if(isset($node->get('field_link'))) {
    // perform some logic. 

   ksm('in here'); // printed multiple times. 
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it running five times for each node?

Comment: @mpdonadio yes, we are noticing `ksm('in here')` showing up five times.

Comment: But is `$node->nid` the same for each?  And since you tagged 8, do you have render cache and/or Twig caching disabled?

Comment: @mpdonadio in our local development environments, we are following [Disable Drupal 8 caching during development](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914)

Comment: You're not calling it manually are you? The question reads as if you are. If you are showing more than one node per page, then it will get called for every node being rendered there. Use a debugger to determine if the entity is the same or not. Printing a static string isn't going to tell you a lot.

Comment: @Kevin that was my issue. It was called for all nodes rendered and so I added a conditional to check for the `#view_mode` and now it is only running once as expected since only one node is rendered with that `view mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. As @Kevin mentioned, it was being called for every node being rendered. I added a condition to check the view more as well and it is being called just one time now.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if(isset($node->get('field_link')) && $variables['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'my_view_mode') {
    // perform some logic. 

   ksm('in here'); // printed once as expected 
  }
}
```